# Loading data into R and getting an error message

Tags: r

I've just tried to load my data into R and got this message

```
> my_data<-read.table(file=file.choose(),header=T,sep="\t")


Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file.choose(), header = T, sep = "\t") :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file.choose(), header = T, sep = "\t") :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file.choose(), header = T, sep = "\t") :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file.choose(), header = T, sep = "\t") :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

Completely confused, any help? This is my data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBpQ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(readxl)

my_data <- read_excel(path = 'pathToYourFile')
```

That's it.

Comment: In case you haven't used it before you'll need to call `install.packages('readxl')` before you run the code in my answer.

Comment: Post your post edit you're still using the wrong function to import the data. There are functions built specifically for Excel, like `read_excel`.